# Logstash is not loading all the records from SQL server

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, sql-server-2012, logstash, kibana

I have been using logstash to load a couple of millions of data into Elasticsearch from SQL server. However, every time I load the data, I am short of few thousands of records.

```
input {
  jdbc {
   jdbc_driver_library => "F:\MG_ES\elasticsearch-5.4.3\elasticsearch-5.4.3\lib\sqljdbc42.jar"
   jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
   jdbc_connection_string => "******"
   jdbc_user => "*******"
   jdbc_password => "*******"
   statement => "select * from ******"
   jdbc_paging_enabled => "true"
   jdbc_page_size => "500000"
   }
}
filter {
    mutate {
        remove_field => [ "message", "path", "score", "@version", "host" ]
    }
    #mutate { convert => ["REGCONNTYPEID","integer"]}
    #mutate { convert => ["data_time_id","integer"]}
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost"
        index => "sql_elk_fct_data"
        document_type => "devices"
        document_id => "%{hwgdid}"
    }
    #stdout { codec => rubydebug { metadata=> true } }
}
```

The query results 2027203 records in Database, however, I can see only the below count in Kibana -

[kibana o/p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgfL6.png)

I got 2298 record less in Elasticsearch index.
hwgdid is the unique and not null field in the query.
What could be the reason?

Comment: How long did you wait before checking the count?

Comment: I waited till the logstash job got completed and checked the count then and the next day as well.

Comment: You are using `document_id => "%{hwgdid}"` maybe you have duplicates in case you have two or more rows with the same `hwgdid`. Try to make an ingestion without setting the document_id, if in the end you have the same number of records, then you have duplicates.